# gprof symspec including C++ class functions

Tags: c++, gprof

I'm trying to profile a particular portion of a large C++ program. I am using gprof and [Gprof2Dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot%20Gprof2Dot) to generate nice graphs. However, I would like to exclude certain startup functions from the graph.

I thought I should be able to run gprof -Qclass::init to supress class::init and all its children, but that doesn't seem to be working. In fact, I can't get any "symspec" containing "::" to work. -Qmain works as I expect, however.

What magic tricks need to be done to get gprof to include/exclude function names with "::"?

Comment: Are you trying to optimize the code, or just get nice graphs? If you're trying to make the code run faster, [you can do better than gprof](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343).